# C - How to check if a process is a system process?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, task, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to detect a fork bomb, and through that process I am trying to caluclate the descendant count of each process. However, I only want to calculate the descendant count for non-system processes, as the fork bomb will be a non-system process. However, I'm unsure how do do that. This is what I have so far:

```
struct task_struct *pTask;
for_each_process(pTask)
{
    struct task_struct *p; 
    *p = *pTask; 

    //trace back to every ancestor 
    for(p = current; p != &init_task; p->parent)
    {
        //increment the descendant count of p's parent            
    }
}
```

This loop goes up to the `init` task correct, since it's `&init_task`? Is there any way to instead to go to the first system process and stop? Because for example, the fork bomb will be the immediate child of a system process. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!!

[EDIT] 
And by system process, I mean like things like for example, `bash`. I should have explained more clearly, but at the basic level, I don't want to delete any process that runs from boot-up. Any processes orginating from user-space that is run after boot up is fair game, but other processes are not. And I will not be checking for anything like `tomcat`,`httpd`, because I know 100% that those processes will not be running.

Comment: what is a "system process?"

Comment: What to you call a *system* process? A process owned by root? What to you think of the `sshd` daemon? What about a `tomcat` or Apache `httpd` (generally **not** run as root) on a web server? Do you want to build a white list? Every process in the system is a grand child of pid 1...

Comment: @SergeBallesta I have updated my question, sorry for the unclear details! Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

A login `bash` shell is `exec`ed by another process (which process depends on whether it is a console login shell, ssh login shell, gnome-terminal shell, etc.)  The process `exec`ing `bash` is `exec`ed by `init` or some other process launched by `init`, not by the kernel.

A user can easily create a bash script that forks itself, so if you exempt `/bin/bash` from your checking then fork bombs written in bash will not be detected.  For example, the following script, put in a file called `foo` and executed in the current directory, will create a fork bomb.

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ /bin/true ]
do
    ./foo &
done
```

Take a look at `ulimit` in [bash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) or [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) if you want to limit the number of processes a particular user can run.

Or, you could set a really high threshold for the descendant count that triggers killing a process.  If the chain of parents back to `init` is several hundred deep, then probably something fishy is going on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [logind](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/logind/) / [ConsoleKit2](http://consolekit2.github.io/ConsoleKit2/) D-Bus APIs to determine the session of a process by its PID. "System" processes (IIRC) will have no session.

Obviously this requires that logind (part of Systemd) or ConsoleKit2 are running.

Without such a service that tracks user sessions, there may be no reliable way to differentiate a "system" process from a user process, except perhaps by user-id (assuming that your fork bomb won't be running as a system user). On many distributions system user IDs are less than 1000, and regular user IDs are >= 1000, except for the "nobody" user (normally 65534).